# How to grab text that is present in alerts using robot framework

Tags: testing, text, robotframework, alerts

I am unable to fetch text that is present in alerts using robot framework. Could someone please help here.

- handle alert  accept      ---> for accepting the alert
- handle alert  dismiss     ---> for rejecting/dismissing the alert

Answer (score 0):

Typically the documentation is really worth to read. Lets start with
https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Handle%20Alert.

Actions are defined to be "DISMISS", "ACCEPT" and "LEAVE". Then, there are examples:

```
Examples:
Handle Alert            # Accept alert.
Handle Alert    action=DISMISS      # Dismiss alert.
Handle Alert    timeout=10 s        # Use custom timeout and accept alert.
Handle Alert    DISMISS     1 min   # Use custom timeout and dismiss alert.
${message} =    Handle Alert        # Accept alert and get its message.
${message} =    Handle Alert    LEAVE   # Leave alert open and get its message.
```

Last example in the *official* documentation.